# Wordpress RSS Feed won't validate

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, rss

If anyone could shed some light on this I would really appreciate it. I've tried every option out there.

the links to the feed is www.edtechlens.com/learning-resources/feed

I keep getting...

```
line 1259, column 67: XML parsing error: <unknown>:1259:67: not well-formed (invalid token)
<description><![CDATA[Rainforest Journey is a vibrant collection of text  ..    
                                                   ^
```

It says it's on the "n" character and I've removed/added both the character and the post to see if that was a hangup. I really have no idea what's causing the error. If I delete the post it moves on to another one.

Comment: You might want to replace the link to the feed with the XML of the feed that results in the error (or the entire feed if it is not very large)

Comment: So it turns out it has to do with the <guid isPermaLink="false"> url. <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.edtechlens.com/?p=107</guid> I believe it has to do with the ?p=107 at the end. I am now using simply exclude plugin to hid these posts from the feed (we don't need them to show up anyway). If anyone has a perma fix for this that'd be helpful.